# Flutter extension method for widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I am concerning about the extensively using extension on Text widget through the entire application

Does anyone knows the extension method will cause the unpleasant performance that similar to helper method vs widget

example:

Creating a custom text extension to avoid a lot boiler code and redundant

```
`extension CustomText on String {
  Widget get largeText => Text(this, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))
}`
```

And later apply for all page:

```
`        Column(
          children: [
            "Welcome".largeText,
            ... other widget
          ],
        )`
```

so using this method is recommended ?

Answer (score 1):

as per name `extension method`. it is a **method**. so it will same like another helper method.

this is simple prove: everytime i call `setState` the welcome text is rebuilt.

[image]

if you just want to add simple style to your `Text` widget, here some options:

- constant `TextStyle`

```
const kLargeTxt = TextStyle(fontSize:20, 
     //another styling here
);
```

use it on to your widget.

```
Text("Welcome", style: kLargeTxt)
```

- another option: set your default `TextStyle` theme in your `MaterialApp`